# Excel Formating a dynamic range as Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which is pulled from a data base.  The data returned is dynamic, both in columns, and rows.  I'm attempting to write a macro to format this data.
I have reviewed a dozen suggestions, but none have worked.

Despite my solutions, I get errors stating "a table cannot overlap a current table" Or a variety of debug errors from trying to set the wrong variable type.
Nothing I have tried works.

```
Sub FormatRawDataTab()
' Formats the Raw Data tab after data refresh

Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet
Dim tblSelect As ListObject

Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate
' Set sht = This Workbook.Sheets("Data")

Range("A1").Select
wrkSheet = Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
wrkSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes).TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium14"
''tblSelect.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium14"

' ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$AO$2959"), , xlYes).Name _
' = "Table1"
' Range("A1:AO2959").Select
' ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your post, is your Table (`ListObject`) already exists in `"Raw Data"` worksheet ? and youjust want to format it ? Or you need to add the Table ?

Comment: The table exists, it's pulled in from the server, and populates the worksheet "Raw Data".  I would like to format the table with TableStyleMedium14.  Thus far, I have been unsuccessful to get the dynamic range, in order to accomplish this. The number of rows and colulmns differ from data pull to data pull.